# Accessing certain words in an split list

Tags: python, list, random, split, shuffle

I am trying to create a program in python that takes a sentence from a user and jumbles the middle letters of said word, but keeping the other letters intact...Right now I have code that will rearrange all the user input's and just forgets about the spaces...I'll let my code speak for myself.. IT works fine for a single word input, I guess I will just summarize it...
I need to randomize each word the user enters keeping the other words intact afterwards..

```
import random


words = input("Enter a word or sentence") #Gets user input

words.split()

for i in list(words.split()): #Runs the code for how many words there are

    first_letter = words[0] #Takes the first letter out and defines it

    last_letter = words[-1] #Takes the last letter out and defines it

    letters = list(words[1:-1]) #Takes the rest and puts them into a list

    random.shuffle(letters) #shuffles the list above

    middle_letters = "".join(letters) #Joins the shuffled list

    final_word_uncombined = (first_letter, middle_letters, last_letter)                       #Puts final word all back  in place as a list

final_word = "".join(final_word_uncombined) #Puts the list back together again

print(final_word) #Prints out the final word all back together again
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost right. Corrected version would be like this:

```
import random

words = raw_input("Enter a word or sentence: ")
jumbled = []

for word in words.split(): #Runs the code for how many words there are
    if len(word) > 2:       # Only need to change long words
        first_letter = word[0] #Takes the first letter out and defines it
        last_letter = word[-1] #Takes the last letter out and defines it
        letters = list(word[1:-1]) #Takes the rest and puts them into a list
        random.shuffle(letters) #shuffles the list above
        middle_letters = "".join(letters) #Joins the shuffled list
        word = ''.join([first_letter, middle_letters, last_letter])

    jumbled.append(word)

jumbled_string = ' '.join(jumbled)
print jumbled_string
```

Comment: I guess my question was misread...I need code that makes it so the first and last letters of every word in a sentence are intact, but the middle is jumbled for each seperate word in a sentence

Comment: But the code seems to do exactly the same, no?


`Enter a word or sentence: I guess my question was misread`
`II guess my qsiuoetn was msaierd`

By the way, there is a bug with one-letter words :)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly it looks like you are on track, you just have to extend this for every word

```
randomized_words = []
for word in words.split():
   #perform your word jumbling
   radomized_words.append(jumbled_word)

print ' '.join(randomized_words)
```

This creates a separate jumbled word list.  Each word in the users word input is jumbled and added to the list to retain order.  At the end, the jumbled words list is printed. Each word is in the same order as entered by the user but the letters are jumbled.

Answer (score 0):

So I read this question, during lunch at the apartment, then I had to wade through traffic. Anyways here is my one line contribution. Seriously alexeys' answer is where it's at.

```
sentence = input("Enter a word or sentence")
print " ".join([word[0] + ''.join(random.sample(list(word[1:-1]), len(list(word[1:-1])))) + word[-1] for word in sentence.split()])
```